# error C2059: syntax error : ',' - for macro 'getcwd'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong, 
I get an error msg for line 75:

```
apr_status_t chdir(const char* directory);   
    const char* getcwd() const; \\ln 75  
    static bool exists(const char *progname);
```

which is:

```
process.h(75): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'getcwd'
process.h(75): error C2059: syntax error : ','
```

This is definition of getcwd()

```
const char* AprProcess::getcwd() const {
    return mpWorkingDir ? mpWorkingDir : "";
}
```

Do You have any ideas? I guess is something with [declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or way I call getcwd().
(I'm moving my code to VS 2010)

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove the code and make it useless for other people. If you do need them deleting because you'll get into trouble, you can click on the Flag link, and ask a moderator to do it for you.

Comment: ok I will do like that

Comment: You can't delete your question after there are upvoted answers, and removing the code from your question has the effect of making the question invalid - which isn't fair to the answerers, upvoters, and readers who find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone has put in a preprocessor `#define` for `getcwd`.

Try putting an `#undef getcwd` before your line 75 and see if it fixes the problem.

To find the culprit, it might help to do a `#define getcwd` yourself at the very top of your `.cpp` file, before including any headers. If you are lucky, you will get a compiler error at the place were the original `#define` happens.

Comment: @Pankow: Now you should take the rest of ComicSansMS's advice (except his font recommendation) to find the true _cause_ of the problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Death to Helvetica! :P